# Connecting to mongohq db from digital ocean express-train app

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

How do I give my user permissions to set TTL index on the collection sessions?

```
[express train application listening on 3000]
Exiting process due to uncaught exception!
Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions <MongoError: not authorized for query on dbname.system.indexes>
    at /var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:139:23
    at /var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1227:28
    at /var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1371:30
    at /var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:156:22
    at /var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:611:39
    at Cursor.close (/var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:939:5)
    at commandHandler (/var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/cursor.js:611:21)
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/www/domain.com/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1709:18)
    at g (events.js:175:14)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
```

I am using https://github.com/Khelldar/Angular-Express-Train-Seed and simply updating the configuration file to point to mongohq. Is this a limitation of the library and connecting to external hosts from digital ocean or a permission I need to add for the user I'm logging in as?